# How could I import a Persistence provider from an external jar to my Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jpa, configuration

I have created a Maven project with some services that use JPA to connect to my database, this project contains the file persistence.xml with all the config needed.
Now I want to import the jar of that project into a new Spring Boot project in order to use all those services, but when I run the Spring Boot project I get an error.

I have tried to import my services jar in another (non Spring Boot) project and that works, so I think that some config of Spring Boot may be overriding mine.

I have my services project dependency on my pom as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.test.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>ServicesProject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

My persistence.xml file has this config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:l521/orcl"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I get this error when I run the Spring Boot app:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default

Comment: Have you imported Configuration Files from ServicesProject? also have u added packages from ServicesProject in your component  scan ?

Comment: I want to notice that my services are not Spring services, ServicesProject is a JavaEE project with JPA. No Spring and nothing related.